# How to import a module from a package in different folder directory?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import, python-module, pythonpath

I have created **init**.py file on all my folders which should be essentially packaged the folder as a package.
I keep getting a 'No module named 'xxx.xxx' message.

The IntelliSense on visual studio however shows the module.

I have tried adding 
1. import line on the 'init' file on the folders
2. import line on the main file from which i am trying to access the module
3. 'from x import y' on the mainfile

```py
import os
import ml
import ml.controller
from ml import controller

Project setup on visual studio-

ProjectName
--ml(folder)
    -__init__.py
    -controller(folder)
       -__init__.py
       -classification(folder)
           -__init__.py
           -k-means.py
runserver.py
I am trying to access the k-means.py class from runserver.py.
```

I except to import the module on my main file.

Comment: Check that your PYTHONPATH has the path to the module that you are trying to import.

Comment: @NicoT the 'sys.path' gets me 'C:\\xxx\FirstProj\\ProjectName' which is the folder location on the project.

Comment: It was an issue with the folder name, the solution view on the Solution Explorer showed "**controller**" but when i switched to the folder view the name was '**Controller**'. The csproj and all other places in the code had used `import ml.controller` but the folder could not be found because of its name.